# DIV element relative HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m loading the content of an external HTML file using jQuery and setting the contents to a DIV element.  The HTML renders correctly inside the DIV, however any relative URLs for images do not load – understandable as they are relative to the HTML file location.

What would be the best way to ensure all relative content is also loaded?
I could dynamically change all of the relative URLs to absolute ones using JavaScript, but is there an easier way todo this or a more preferred approach?

Comment: root relative would be fine i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your relative URLs to static/relative to current HTML page in which you are loading the file. Consider following example, suppose you are loading html named page1.html :

```
$.get('html/pages/page1.html', {}, function(data, status, xhr) {
    var updatedData = data.replace(/\.\.\/(images|css|js)+/g, "http://www.mywebsite.com/html/$1");
    $('#content').html(updatedData);
});
```

This isn't the best programming practice, as it is not as flexible (going from relative to absolute in this type of context is relying on a number of factors working properly) as it should be, but it will work.